# Vuetify list-item-group, an Array in value prop of list-item?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Am using a list-item-group vuetify component.

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <v-list flat>
    <v-list-item-group multiple v-model="visibleColumns">
      <v-list-item :value="first">
        //...Nothing important here
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item-group>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

It would be very useful if in the prop value i could use an array directly, kind of like this:

```
<v-list-item :value="['First', 'Second']">
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 <v-list-item
    v-for="(item, i) in ['First', 'Second']"
    :key="i"
 >
```